# Programmatically Create Wireless Ad-Hoc Network

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, wireless, opennetcf

How do i setup a wireless ad-hoc network to Windows Mobile 6.1 on startup? I think the only way to do this is programmatically and I have been unable to find a way to create a network, I have found OpenNetCF but is there a way to do this in .NET CF? Or how-to do it in OpenNetCF?

I need to do this so I can have socket communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another name for Ad-hoc is "not Infrastructure Mode", so if you look at some of [the example service code that I have here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/08/19/AServiceForScanningAndConnectingToWiFiNetworksFromTheCF.aspx), you'll see a private method that looks like this:

```
private bool ConnectToNetwork(
    string ssid, 
    string passphrase, 
    bool adhoc, 
    AuthenticationMode mode, 
    WEPStatus encryption)
{
    // other setup code, etc
                return m_wzc.AddPreferredNetwork(ssid,  
                    !adhoc,  
                    passphrase,  
                    1,  
                    mode,  
                    encryption,  
                    eap);  
}
```

Notice how it's passing the bool parameter for infrastructure mode as the second parameter.  You simply need to add another public method that calls into ConnectToNetwork that sets this to true (every method in the service right now passes false because I didn't have Ad-hoc as a requirement when I wrote the code).

Comment: Good Morning, Chris! I haven't even had my coffee yet! :)

Comment: But this can only connect to a network right? Not create a network... is there a method to create a network? I just need to be able to communicate through a socket connection for localhost, don't really need to communicate at all with the outside.

Comment: No, this will create the network connection - notice the WZC call is "AddPreferredNetwork".  Not sure what you mean by "localhost".  If you are simply talking to yourself through a socket (like for IPC or something) then I would think you don't even need to create a network, just create a socket to the loopback address.